# how to rewrite `delegate` pattern javascript code in typescript

Tags: typescript

Hot to rewrite the following javascript code in typescipt?

```
const handlers = {
  say (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  },
  add (a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
}

function caller (method, ...args) {
  if (handlers[method]) return handlers[methd](...args)
  throw new Error(`${method} not found`)
}
```

I have more than 100 functions in `handlers` which separated into several files, `handlers` provide apis for other modules, and the `caller` provide a unified entrance for these apis.

Every functions has been rewrite in typescipt correctly. But when came into the function `caller`, I'm confused, is there any way to rewrite it and keep the type info of callees?

I've made some attempts, but none work out at the end :(  The following is one of them, may be close to the right solution.

```
type AlterReturnType<K, T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
  T extends () => any ? (k: K) => ReturnType<T> :
  T extends (a: infer A) => any ? (k: K, a: A) => ReturnType<T> :
  T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B) => any ? (k: K, a: A, b: B) => ReturnType<T> :
  T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C) => any ? (k: K, a: A, b: B, c: C) => ReturnType<T> :
  T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D) => any ? (k: K, a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => ReturnType<T> :
  T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, e: infer E) => any ? (k: K, a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => ReturnType<T> :
  never

type Handlers = typeof handlers
type HandleKeys = keyof Handlers

interface IHandlerObject {
  [k: string]: (...args: any[]) => any
}

type GetCaller<T extends IHandlerObject> = {
  [k in keyof T]: AlterReturnType<k, T[k]>
}

type Caller = GetCaller<Handlers>[keyof Handlers]

const caller: Caller = function name (method: string, ...args: any[]) {
  // do know how to rewrite the following
  // @ts-ignore
  if (handlers[method]) return handlers[method](...args)
  throw new Error(`${method} not found`)
}

// TS error occurred:
//   [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((k: "say", a: any) => void) | ((k: "add", a: any, b: any) => any)' has no compatible call signatures.
caller('say', 'ggg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've managed to produce a union of the correct call signatures, but what you need is an intersection.  By searching [src/compiler/checker.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/src/compiler/checker.ts) for calls to `getIntersectionType`, I found you can do that by (ab)using contravariant type inference:

```
type Caller1 = GetCaller<Handlers>;
type Caller =
  {[k in keyof Caller1]: (p: Caller1[k]) => void} extends
    {[n: string]: (p: infer T) => void} ? T : never;
```

Edit: See [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) for a similar technique with more explanation.

Comment: It works, brilliant ! Thank you! But not understand how these codes work